# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111 when calling function with rowtype return value

Tags: oracle, ojdbc, callable-statement

I have a function in an Oracle package call "MyPackage":

```
FUNCTION MyFunction(name IN VARCHAR2) RETURN MyTable%rowtype;
```

Which I am attempting to call via JDBC.

```
CallableStatement cs = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call MyPackage.MyFunction(?) }");`
cs.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.OTHER);
cs.setString(2, "SomeString");
cs.executeQuery();
```

I get

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type: 1111
```

I have tried using OracleTypes.CURSOR and OracleTypes.REF but all have issues. I am wondering if I need to define a STRUCT or something along those lines but because the return value isn't a named type I don't think I can use that?

I have also tried:

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate);
call.withCatalogName("MYPACKAGE")
    .withFunctionName("MYFUNCTION");

SqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("NAME", "SomeString");

Map<String, Object> map = call.execute(paramMap);
```

Which also yields the Invalid column type 1111 error. 
The column metadata says that the argument is OracleTypes.OTHER

The code I used to verify the column metadata was:

```
DatabaseMetaData dbMeta = connection.getMetaData();

ResultSet rs =  dbMeta.getProcedureColumns(null, "MYSCHEMA", "%MY_FUNCTION%", "%");

while (rs.next()) {
    String procedureName = rs.getString(3);
    String columnName = rs.getString(4);
    int dataType = rs.getInt(6);
     System.out.println("Procedure Name: " + procedureName + ", Column Name: " + columnName + ", Data Type:" + dataType);
}
```

The output from this was:

```
Procedure Name: MYFUNCTION, Column Name: null, Data Type:1111
Procedure Name: MYFUNCTION, Column Name: NAME, Data Type:12
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I may be too late on this question but for someone who still have this issue might be assisted.

in your function, you specified an in parameter(`IN name`) but in your callableStatement you registering an out parameter that is not included in your function. To get your table rawtype you may use both function and procedure. for procedure use

```
PROCEDURE MyFunction(results OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,name IN VARCHAR2);
```

Then in your callable statement, you can register an out parameter just like how you did.

For the function, you can do this

```
FUNCTION MyFunction(name IN VARCHAR2) RETURN MyTable%rowtype;
```

Then your java code will be

```
SimpleJdbcCall executor = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withSchemaName("schema_name").withCatalogName("packageName").withFunctionName("myFunction");
            
MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("NAME", someString);

List<Map<String, Object>> tablerow = executor.executeFunction(String.class, param);
```

The error is caused by registering an out parameter which is parameter type 111 that is not defined in your function.